# Does runtime of an algorithm depends on processor?

Tags: algorithm, processor

I have given a project for finding all the primes below N.And for this the test case timeout condition is [TestMethod, Timeout(1000)],which means our algorithm should execute in <1sec.

When i run the same program on i5 processor it ran successfully but when i run it on i3 the testcases failed because of timeout error.

**Does the runtime of an algorithm depends on processor?**

**What are the factors that effects run time of an algorithm?**

Comment: Time complexity is a theoretical construct that depends only upon the implementation of an algorithm. In practice, a processor may implement features (caching for example) that can artificicially reduce time complexity somewhat.

Comment: The complexity of an algorithm, e.g. as a function of the size of the input, simply tells us how the running time or space requirements scale.  The actual running time may vary depending on the processor/environment used.

Comment: I wouldn't say it reduces *time complexity*, it can reduce some time constants/scaling factors of the various operations (and the "somewhat" is often tenfold or more).

Comment: That's fair, I didn't really put that well. I think the issue is talking about "algorithms running on processors" which is sort of an abuse of vocabulary. I'll leave my comment up as the discussion may be valuable to the asker and appreciate your clarification!

Comment: For your updated question: Of course does the runtime of a program depend on the processor. Why else would anybody buy a new processor instead of sticking with a $10 processor from the 90s? There are quite a lot of factors that influence runtime. Stating all of them is too broad for the SO format.

Comment: Generally speaking questions about asymptotic complexity would be better on the [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), but take a look at the existing resources (e.g. Wikipedia) before posting - this question is essentially just confirming well established definitions.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the runtime of an algorithm depends on processor?

Of course execution time depends on processor. That's why companies like Intel spend vast amounts of money on producing faster and faster processors.

For example: if an algorithm consists of 1 million operations, and a CPU is capable of performing 1 million operations per second, executing that algorithm would take 1 second. On the other hand, given a processor with performance of 10 million operations per second, that algorithm would take only 0.1s. That's very simplified example, as not every instruction takes the same time, and there's more factors involved (cache, memory bandwidth, special instructions like SSE), but it illustrates general point: faster processor executes code in shorter time - that's the point of faster processors.

**Note:** that's totally unrelated to [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).